# Top panel position fixed

Tags: html, css

I want my panel at the top of my page to be fixed.
Here is an example of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/QuantumHive/pNZx4/
If I add `position:fixed;` to the panel, the panel just resizes itself. I want the black panel to be full width. It does however scroll with the page. I just don't understand why this is changing the divs entire width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding `width: 100%` to the panel?

With that, you'll also need to add `padding-top: 40px` to the #logowrapper to cater for the height of the panel.

Finally, I added `margin: 0; padding: 0` to the body to make everything full width of the browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/pNZx4/3/

Comment: Thank you, you're awesum! But I still don't understand why the panel's width would resize if I added `position:fixed;` in my case?

Comment: When you set an element's position to fixed you are taking the element out of the normal flow, and positioning it according to the viewport. It will now only be as wide as it's content, rather than being as wide as it's parent.  In your case, it's the width of the longest `<li>` plus the margin and padding that's been added to `#mainwidth`.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So that's why the `#logowrapper` also get's shifted upwards. To fix that hack you added `padding-top:40px;`. Wouldn't this cause layout issues on different resolutions?

Comment: Another fix for that is to set padding: 40px to the body.  This is the technique Bootstrap use for their 'navbar-fixed'.
You can define a min-height for the panel of 40px.  Different resolutions shouldn't cause an issue here.

Comment: Thanks! Your answers made me fully comprehend this matter.